# What is the distribution of colour in an image relative to defined centroids

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Let's say I have the following picture:

[image]

And the following "reference" colours which are static and not determined from the images (in RGB)

1. [90, 160, 155]
2. [245, 210, 110]
3. [20, 20, 20]
4. [150, 150, 120]

How do I get a return object that tells me, per reference colour, the percentage of colours in the image that are "closest" to the reference colour with a return value like such:

```
{
  "colour1": 0.25, // These aren't the actual distributions, but the answer
  "colour2": 0.1,  // this is trying to represent is that 25% of the colour
  "colour3": 0.6,  // in the image is closest to "colour1", 10% of the
  "colour4": 0.05  // image is closest to "colour2", etc.
}
```

Is there a performant way to do this, so that a result could be returned for a large image within a couple of seconds and with a dozen reference colours?

The answer doesn't need to be an exact, an approximation within 10% would be ok, so if reducing the size of the picture dramatically is the way to speed it up then that's ok.

---

My first (and awful - it was just for a quick proof of concept) pass solution was:

1. Loop through all of the pixels in the picture
2. Loop through all of the reference colours
3. Calculate the Euclidian distance between the pixel colour and reference colour
4. Return the reference colour with the closest Euclidian distance
5. Count the occurrences of each reference colour in the result and divide by total number of pixels to get percentage

Of course, this is slow

My next steps, I've been thinking of trying a couple of different options:

1. Use opencv to generate a colour histogram and somehow use the result of that to get to the percentage of each reference colour
2. Use K-means clustering, setting the reference colours as the centroids, and use the result of that

But I thought I would ask on here first before diving in to see if anybody has recommendations on where to go, or even better, if there's a simple library that could solve this problem without much effort.

Comment: Have you tried something? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: For each color range use `inRange` function, compute all non-zero pixels in the destination image, divide that number by total number of pixels in the src image.

Comment: I've updated the question with my approaches / guesses thus far @mkrieger1

Comment: @zindarod - I've tried this one already but it doesn't perform that well. Maybe the best solution is just forcing the image down to a small size and running this strategy against that.

Comment: 0) init a # colors histogram at 0, 1) loop image, 2) loop colors, 3) find the closest color 4) add 1 in the histogram at closest color index, 5) normalize L1 the histogram, 6) done. I don't see how this could take more than 2 seconds. Looping in python is slower... probably some indexed approach is faster. But 2 seconds should be more than enough

Comment: How large an image and on what hardware do you need the 2 seconds performance? Pretty sure Halide can take care of that for a pretty broad set of parameters. Will see if I can get some time later to try. This would be brute force, but taking advantage of parallelism in the hardware and a specific compiled implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your "awful" solution is probably the fastest for a small number of reference colors. For every pixel you need to find the smallest distance to those references, by exhaustive comparison (note anyway that you can dispense yourself with the square roots).

If you find it too slow, you might consider switching to a compiled language.

For a larger number of colors, you can start thinking of a k-D tree (k=3) which will speedup the search for the nearest color a little. But don't expect miracles.

For an approximate solution, you can consider building a low resolution lookup-table with, say, 32 bins per color component to achieve the 10% accuracy requirement. This makes a total of 32³=32768 bins, which you will initialize with the index of the nearest color, computed as above. This takes the same time as to fill a 32768 pixels image. When the table is available, this reduces the handling of every pixel to a simple table lookup.

If the same references are used for several or larger images, you can consider using a more accurate lookup-table. If your references are really static and you can afford 24 MB of storage, you can map the whole RGB space.

Final note: every step of the k-means procedure is precisely performing the nearest-neighbor assignment task, and your percentages just come as a byproduct. If you have an optimized k-means handy, with access to the cluster sizes and an option to set the initial centers, use it and perform a single iteration.

Comment: This task is also highly parallelizable

Comment: Unless he uses a GPU, will his manual looping be as optimized as opencv's functions? Specially if opencv has been built with a parallel framework?

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking of a significant speedup you could achieve when the image has large, uniform areas.

If you decompose the image as a mosaic, the pixels in a tile will occupy some volume of RGB space. If it turns out that all the points of this volume map to the same reference, you can assign all pixels in a single go.

Using the lookup-table trick described in my other post, while initializing the table you can determine which bins (cubes in RGB space) map to a single reference color. Then if the bounding box of the volume wholly fits in a cube, you are done.

A more sophisticated version would work with an octree representation of RGB space, where every node (corresponding to a cube of some size) contains the list of nearest colors its content maps to (for a nice distribution of the reference colors, many nodes will have a list of one or two colors. Then for a given tile, you compute the bounding boxes of the color it contains, and a search inside the octree wil return a list of possible colors. In case the list is a singleton you are done. Otherwise, you classify against a reduced number of colors.

Answer (score 0):

I used array operations to improve the performance. Roughly speaking I did the same: evaluate the distance for each pixel and to each color and count for the winner (small distance).

[image]

I just see your question is on Python and my code is in C++. However see if it can help you to find your solution in Python.

```
Scalar color1(155, 160, 90);
Scalar color2(110, 210, 245);
Scalar color3(20, 20, 20);
Scalar color4(120, 150, 150);

void compare(Mat& targetDistance, Mat& distanceToCompareA,
        Mat& distanceToCompareB, Mat& distanceToCompareC, String name) {

    Mat compareA = targetDistance - distanceToCompareA;
    Mat thresholdMatA;
    threshold(compareA, thresholdMatA, 0, 1, THRESH_BINARY_INV);

    Mat compareB = targetDistance - distanceToCompareB;
    Mat thresholdMatB;
    threshold(compareB, thresholdMatB, 0, 1, THRESH_BINARY_INV);

    Mat compareC = targetDistance - distanceToCompareC;
    Mat thresholdMatC;
    threshold(compareC, thresholdMatC, 0, 1, THRESH_BINARY_INV);

    Mat thresholdMat;
    bitwise_and(thresholdMatA, thresholdMatB, thresholdMat);

    bitwise_and(thresholdMat, thresholdMatC, thresholdMat);

    Size size = thresholdMat.size();

    double distro = ceil(sum(thresholdMat)[0] * 100 / (size.height * size.width))/100.0;

    cout << name << " " << distro << endl;

    Mat dest = thresholdMat * 255.0;

    Mat output;
    dest.convertTo(output, CV_8UC1);

    namedWindow(name, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow(name, output);
}

int main() {

    Mat origin = imread("XwAAB.jpg");

    Mat src;
    origin.convertTo(src, CV_16SC1);

    Mat matColor1 = Mat(src.size(), src.type());
    matColor1.setTo(color1);

    Mat matColor2 = Mat(src.size(), src.type());
    matColor2.setTo(color2);

    Mat matColor3 = Mat(src.size(), src.type());
    matColor3.setTo(color3);

    Mat matColor4 = Mat(src.size(), src.type());
    matColor4.setTo(color4);

    Mat sub = src - matColor1;
    Mat pow = sub.mul(sub);
    Mat distance1;
    transform(pow, distance1, cv::Matx13f(1, 1, 1));

    sub = src - matColor2;
    pow = sub.mul(sub);
    Mat distance2;
    transform(pow, distance2, cv::Matx13f(1, 1, 1));

    sub = src - matColor3;
    pow = sub.mul(sub);
    Mat distance3;
    transform(pow, distance3, cv::Matx13f(1, 1, 1));

    sub = src - matColor4;
    pow = sub.mul(sub);
    Mat distance4;
    transform(pow, distance4, cv::Matx13f(1, 1, 1));

    compare(distance1, distance2, distance3, distance4, "color1");

    compare(distance2, distance1, distance3, distance4, "color2");

    compare(distance3, distance1, distance2, distance4, "color3");

    compare(distance4, distance1, distance2, distance3, "color4");

    namedWindow("origin", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("origin", origin);
    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```